# How to add anotation to my pdf using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios-pdfkit

I'm fairly new to objective c and Apple's PdfKit framework and i'm unable to draw anotations on top of my pdf.

I get no errors on the console.
This is my code :

```
PDFAnnotation  * observation = [[PDFAnnotation alloc] init];
CGRect cgRect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 120, 120);
                
observation.widgetFieldType = PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtypeButton;
observation.bounds = cgRect;
observation.shouldDisplay = true;
observation.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
observation.widgetFieldType= PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtypeButton;
                
[page addAnnotation:observation];
```

Does someone know why my pdfanotation is not drawn on my pdf ?
I'm also wondering if the PdfKit framework is fully supported on objective c as the apple's documentation for it just has examples that are made using swift.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your annotation is not drawn because you forgot to set the `type`. It's probably a mistake, because you're setting `widgetFieldType` twice. Here's the correct button widget setup:

```c
PDFAnnotation  *observation = [[PDFAnnotation alloc] init];
observation.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 100);

observation.type = PDFAnnotationSubtypeWidget;
observation.widgetFieldType = PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtypeButton;
observation.widgetControlType = kPDFWidgetCheckBoxControl;

observation.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
[page addAnnotation:observation];
```

To avoid future mistakes like this one, use the following initializer:

```c
- (instancetype)initWithBounds:(CGRect)bounds 
                       forType:(PDFAnnotationSubtype)annotationType 
                withProperties:(NSDictionary *)properties;
```

And change the setup code to:

```c
PDFAnnotation  *observation = [[PDFAnnotation alloc] initWithBounds:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 100)
                                                            forType:PDFAnnotationSubtypeWidget
                                                     withProperties:nil];
observation.widgetFieldType = PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtypeButton;
observation.widgetControlType = kPDFWidgetCheckBoxControl;
observation.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    
[page addAnnotation:observation];
```

I'd highly recommend to setup appearance (like `backgroundColor`) as the last thing. Because all these values are modified by PDFKit when you change the type.

Also be aware that `0, 0` is bottom/left corner (`bounds`).

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know if there is a way to draw a picture instead of a button as an annotation ?

Comment: IIRC you can't add it as an annotation, but you can draw it (with some drawbacks) - see [Inserting an Image into a PDF](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/insert-image-into-pdf-with-swift/) for example. It's in Swift, but you can easily rewrite it to Obj-C.

Comment: ah. I want to place clickable pointers on top of my PDF do you know if i could instead of drawing a clickable picture draw a custom clickable annotation ? Thanks